# A Style Resource related 'Widget' error in android application --

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-resources

I'll describe my problem first. I'm trying an android app. Doing it using Xamarin Android. I've done the parts I need, the necessary code; but Compiling my code gives me some errors in the Styles.xml file.

The error is like this::

**Error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget'. (APT0000) (TestALLApp)**
Basically 5 errors, the above error repeating itself 5 times for the 5 style definitions in the Stylex xml file.

This is my Styles.xml file::

```
<resources>
<style name="Widget.SampleContentContainer">  <---- error shown here
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/vertical_page_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/vertical_page_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/horizontal_page_margin</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/horizontal_page_margin</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.SampleDashboard.Grid" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:stretchMode">columnWidth</item>
    <item name="android:columnWidth">200dp</item>
    <item name="android:numColumns">auto_fit</item>
    <item name="android:drawSelectorOnTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
    <item name="android:verticalSpacing">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.SampleDashboard.Item" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/sample_dashboard_item_background</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/margin_small</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.SampleDashboard.Item.Title" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/margin_tiny</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#09c</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.SampleDashboard.Item.Description" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

You can see the line on which the error is shown. Among the references I added to my project were

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView

That's All. As per the error message I suppose, 'Error retrieving parent for item' should mean it cannot find/locate a parent called 'Widget'. I did search for any nuget package like Xamarin Widget, anything of that name or similar name doesn't exist. At least my nuget package search cannot list/find anything like that. Or is it something to do with a style element definition called 'Widget' too in that xml file? So what is the actual correct thing to be done please, if someone could show me, it'd help me very much. Is it just a missing nuget package? If so what is the proper correct name of it please['widget'].
Please help me a little on this matter.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

As I have used it before, the parent attribute's value is the parent style that you will start with, then override the various properties within there.  For me, I have always used parent attribute values such as "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light", .Dark, and so on.  Unless there is a theme named Widget, I don't see this working.

PS.  Obviously, the holo styles were first introduced in android 3.x/4.x, so I doubt that they would work in previous versions of android without including some other stuff to make them work.  You used the Xamarin.Forms tag for the question, so this won't be a big deal since XF only runs on android 4 and later.

Comment: Hi Wallace,
Thanks so much for replying.

Okay, then:::
<style name="Widget" />

I guess I can incorporate 'Widget' into my styles xml file like that? Or any other theme I want to use? This should work, isn't it.